# How to change build display name for scheduled job using groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have triggered another job using below groovy post build script and I would like to change the build display name for the triggered job (not for current job). How do we do it?

```
def another = job.scheduleBuild(0, new Cause.UpstreamCause(manager.build), new ParametersAction(params))
```

This is just schedules a build but doesn't wait for completion of the build. (unlike `job.scheduleBuild2` method)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to give the job a parameter buildName which has a default value but can also be set by upstream jobs.

You also might want to use [build](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) instead of job.scheduleBuild which does essentially the same but is far more readable.

It would look something like this:

```
build job: "jobName", parameters: [string(name: 'buildName', value: '<yourBuildName>'), ...]
```

In the other job you would use the [Build Name Setter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) Plugin:

```
buildName param.buildName
```